# CS50 pset9 finance buy handles valid purchase error

Tags: cs50

I am trying to finish C$50 finance problem set. I got an error in the /buy method when I tried to check50. I tried every way but failed, I changed quite a few things in the code. I guess I just made things worse.

The error code is:

:( buy handles valid purchase
Cause
expected to find "112.00" in page, but it wasn't found
Log
sending GET request to /signin
sending POST request to /login
sending POST request to /buy
checking that "112.00" is in page

https://submit.cs50.io/check50/319ecaf976ce22ca7ff2a6b243d733575883bc48

Here is my app.py

```
"""Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("buy.html")
    else:
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")



        if not symbol:
            return apology("Symbol is blank")

        stock = lookup(symbol.upper())

        if stock == None:
            return apology("Symbol does not Exists")


        
        if not request.form.get("shares"):
            return apology("Please key in number of shares!", 400)
        if not request.form.get("shares").isdigit():
            return apology("Please key in a positive integer!", 400)
        if not float(request.form.get("shares")).is_integer() or float(request.form.get("shares")) < 1:
            return apology("Please key in a positive integer!", 400)
        
        try:
            shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
        except ValueError:
            return apology("shares must be a posative integer", 400)
        
        if shares<0:
            return apology("Share is not allowed")
        
        transaction_value = shares * stock["price"]

        user_id = session["user_id"]
        user_cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)[0]['cash']

        
        if user_cash<transaction_value:
            return apology("Not Enough Money")

        uptd_cash = user_cash - transaction_value

        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id =?",uptd_cash,user_id)

        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        new_user= db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,symbol,shares,price,date) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",user_id,stock["symbol"],shares,stock["price"],date)

        flash("Bought!")

        return redirect("/")
```

Here is my buy.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    BUY
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<h1>
    BUY
</h1>
    <form action="/buy" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto"  name="symbol" placeholder="Symbol" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto"  name="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="text">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buy</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Please help me about this.

On interface, I can run buy function without problem. But when I enter 112.00, it gives me error 400.

Comment: From @JaimeHutchins (not enough rep. to post it as a comment): *Getting the same issue, seems the issue is not on the buy page but the index page as output is here and not the buy page.

With that in mind have you checked the values are displayed in usd (ie $112.00), like {{ value | usd }} in jinja, seems to fix it for some people?*